# How to loop through ROT1-ROT25

Tags: perl, loops

I have it set up so far that it decodes a ROT25 encrypted message and reads it only displaying if has the word "the" in it. But I have to make it go through every ROT(1-25). I know its probably a loop but not sure how to set it up.

```
use English;

my $file_name = shift;

sub decode
{
    return shift =~ tr/Z-ZA-Yz-za-y/A-Za-z/r;
}

open(my $file_handle, '<', $file_name)
or die "Could not open file '$file_name' $!";

my $encoded = '';

{   # allow us to read entire file in as a string:

    local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef;

    $encoded = <$file_handle>;
}

close $file_handle;

my $decoded = &decode($encoded);

if ($decoded=~m/(^| )the/)  # make this more robust!
{
    print($decoded);
}else{
print("File does not contain the, not the secret file");
}
```

Comment: See rot 13; [User Contributed Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
my $decoded = $encoded;
for my $rot (reverse 1..25) {
    $decoded = decode($decoded);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
my $decoded = $encoded;
my $decodingFound;
for (1 .. 25) {
    $decoded = decode($decoded);
    if ($decoded =~ /\bthe\b/) {
        print($decoded);
        $decodingFound = 1;
        last;
    }
}

print("File does not contain the, not the secret file")
    unless $decodingFound;
```

Notes:

- this tries all the ROTs from ROT1 to ROT25
- it never checks the original (encoded) string; to do that, loop 26 instead of 25 times
- as soon as it finds *a* rotation that contains "the", it stops looking
- the regular expression is `\bthe\b`: the `\b` means word binaries, so neither `"there"` nor `"father"` will match; it seems that's what you wanted, judging by your comment ("make this more robust!")

Also, your rotation may be shortened to `tr/ZA-Yza-y/A-Za-z/r` (`Z` is as good as `Z-Z`) and may be more legible as `tr/A-Za-z/B-ZAb-za/r`.